# How to properly secure query strings that are being sent to server?

Tags: php, security

I am creating a social application and I'd like to know how to secure it in a way that if someone, somehow, gets to the parameters I'm sending to the server doesn't screw up everything in my database, i.e. change and insert data in the database just by sending requests to the server with the right parameters.
I'm going to create both web and mobile versions first and I'll secure the communication from client to server by implementing HTTPS. But, the thing is that you can still get to the parameters by using a proxy that acts like a MiTM, just like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) does.
Will using TOTP as another parameter do the job, or should I use some kind of authentication?
For the record, I'm using PHP on the server-side and Java as the Android application, which I'm going to create first. Then, I'll create Windows Phone and iOS applications later on as well.
Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am not trying to prevent MiT, as some of you down mentioned.
I am aware that I can't hide the parameters from the client that are being sent to the server and I'm not trying to prevent that either.
What I am trying to prevent is the following:
Let's assume the app sends the following string query:

```
uid=75&deactivate=1
```

To the following file:

```
https://www.example.com/users.php
```

I don't want someone to do a simple loop and send requests to the server with user IDs. It doesn't even have to be a loop. Everyone can deactivate random peoples' accounts. Or maybe change their information by putting the right parameters in the query string.
There needs to be some sort of protection for this thing. I thought that this could be solved by adding another parameter which only the app and the server would know that it is valid and will serve as some kind of authentication.
What is the proper way to solve this problem?!

Comment: "gets to the parameters I'm sending to the server doesn't screw up everything in my database" --- it should not be a problem in the very first place. You see the plain url of this page. So - try to screw the stackoverflow.com's database with it?

Comment: Another point: you cannot hide it from the client. If your application can send a request - there is always a way to forge it, no exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

> But, the thing is that you can still get to the parameters by using a proxy that acts like a MiTM, just like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) does.

If your threat model is "the user might be vulnerable to a MitM", your options are:

1. Use a CA-signed TLS certificate
2. Use Hypertext Strict Transport Security
3. Use HTTP Public-Key-Pinning
4. All of the above

If your threat model is "someone might try to tamper with their outbound requests by using a MitM proxy", don't bother trying to prevent that. Instead, validate your input.

---

Recommended reading:

- [Client authenticity is not the server's problem](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem)

  - You cannot prevent clients from being malicious.
- [The comprehensive guide to URL parameter encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

  - Many people try to reach for cryptography to solve problems, but the tools cryptographers have given us all have narrower use cases than developers often believe.

Comment: I edited the question and added more explanation about the problem. Can you take a look at it, please? Thanks!